# How do I safely rename my mac hardrive "Macintosh HD"?

Tags: macos, osx-lion

I installed an SSD in my main hard drive bay and moved my platter HD to the optical bay. I now run my applications off the SSD and my home folder of the platter drive.

I'm trying to install RVM and I think the space in the "Macintosh HD" is causing a problem. Any tips/fixes?

Comment: I don't know about safely, but you could simply get up the info pane and change the name under `Name & Extension`.

Comment: Unless you're trying to do this in code this isn't the correct forum. For future ref. check out http://superuser.com/

Answer (score 4):

You can edit the name through Finder `-> get info`. It won't break anything, according to information found [here](http://forums.macrumors.com/showthread.php?t=1295428).