# Why doesn't Android Studio accept new Java JDK location

Tags: android-studio, android-studio-2.1

I am trying to change the JDK location from "C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.7.0_09" to "C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_25", but Android Studio seems to ignore the change completely.  The location remains "C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.7.0_09".

Could anyone offer a tip on how to remedy this?

I have tried many times and restarted AS a few times. I must be missing something fundamental.
[image]
[image]
[image]

Comment: check your firewall settings, I had to allow it through my firewall when I switched

Comment: @quidproquo Thank you for the comment. I have just tried it with the firewall disabled, but it did not make any difference. I have just realized that I cannot change anything of the project structure.

Comment: worst comes to worst reinstall android studio I suppose

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this, may be work.

Android studio don't accept a SDK path that contains a whitespace.
 In your SDK path, there is a white space between 'Program Files'. Therefore Android Studio showing the error. Solution- Try placing the SDK at 'C:\sdk'. Then change the SDK location in Project Structure.

Comment: Thank you.  This has solved the problem.  The path was like that for 1.5 years since I switched to AS from Eclipse. I saw the warning, but always ignored it because I do not use NDK for this project.  Everything was working fine until I tried to change the JDK path yesterday.

Comment: This is correct. You can also try the following solution: https://stackoverflow.com/a/39816315/5939775