# Android Studio not installing SDK

Tags: android, android-studio

Why am i getting this error? i pretty much tried different solutions like installing sdk again but still getting this error.Please take a look at this error"

[image]

Comment: show us log so that we could help

Comment: See the IDE logs for details.

Comment: The SDK location should not contain whitespace, see [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37052934/android-sdk-location-should-not-contain-whitespace-as-this-cause-problems-with). Move it to something like c:\android\sdk .  See also [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40474050/android-studio-where-to-install-ndk-file-downloaded-it-in-zip/40475804#40475804)

Comment: show Log files please

Comment: it says Please configure sdk

Comment: Keeping the SDK inside the Program Files is not advisable. Move it to 'Local' inside 'AppData'.