# Unable to run sdkmanager - Says not recognized as the name of a cmdlet, function, script file, or operable program

Tags: android

This is the error message I'm getting into when I am trying to install SDK using cmd. Tried many times but can't install it.

```
F:\Softwares\softs\Programming\android sdk tools\bin> sdkmanager
sdkmanager : The term 'sdkmanager' is not recognized as the name of a cmdlet, function, script file, or operable
program. Check the spelling of the name, or if a path was included, verify that the path is correct and try again.
At line:1 char:1
+ sdkmanager
+ ~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : ObjectNotFound: (sdkmanager:String) [], CommandNotFoundException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : CommandNotFoundException
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Android SDK location should not contain whitespace, as this cause problems with NDK tools](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37052934/android-sdk-location-should-not-contain-whitespace-as-this-cause-problems-with)

Comment: Remove spaces from `android sdk tools` folder name .

Comment: You should be using `./sdkmanager` from that folder. Try not using PowerShell, or just use Android Studio to install things

Answer (score 0):

This did not work for me when I tried to run the SDK manager command from PowerShell but *did* work when I ran from the regular old command prompt. I am on windows if that is not obvious.